# Mysql_num_columns? Is there a function equivalent to mysql_num_rows for counting the number of columns?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a function equivalent to `mysql_num_rows` to count the number of columns in a PHP mysql recordset?

If not, rather than just saying so can you please advise me of the best way to make a function that does this.

I have already looked at: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/277417/to-find-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table-using-mysql-query and http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/mysql-number-columns-table-t67489.html but neither of these solutions seem particularly elegant.

Comment: You specify the columns in your query, right? So you should already know how many columns you've got.

Comment: The only situation when you need that is when you do `SELECT * ...`, which is in itself not very good.

Comment: @GolezTrol: and if you change that query you have to remember to update the column count. That would be a nightmare to maintain. While specifying the columns is good practice, keeping track of the column count is certainly a job for a computer, not a human.

Comment: @SoboLAN, I am sure you are very smart but why do you both waste people's time by not answering their questions? Clearly people ask  questions with a goal in mind.

Comment: @Brett, don't take comments personally. And if you have a goal in mind, please add it to your questions. You may get better answers.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Brett, though our comments may not contain a direct answer to your question, they may contain our worries and good advise. Even if hard to imagine, people actually do ask stupid questions sometimes, or sometimes their question itself is good, but it indicates a wrong direction in general. If you feel your question is not stupid and you are on the right track, feel free to ignore the comments, take the first answer for granted and continue as your are now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-fields.php
 mysql_num_fields();

Answer (score 2):

mysql_num_fields : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-fields.php